# Implementing an existing interface which is having @query annotation

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I am implementing an interface in my project(A spring MVC project) which has ten methods. I have implemented two methods and want spring to continue using the interface to query the database unless all of the methods are implemented.
The interface is having @Query annotation and is working fine, but the idea is to implement the method using criteria builder.

My interface

```
@Repository
public interface TagDAO extends JpaRepository<Tag, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT count(*) from Tag t WHERE t.isActive = true")
    public Long getTagCount() throws DataAccessException;
    @Query("SELECT t from Tag t WHERE t.tagName = :tagName")
    public Tag findByTagName(@Param("tagName") String tagName) throws 
    DataAccessException;
    ...........
    rest of the methods
}
```

I have implemented three methods in a class TagDAOImpl but want that the implementation is not to be used in my project unless the implementation is complete.  Is there any way to force the use of interface until I complete the implementation?

Comment: To force the imlementation of the methods just define a `class` repository.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: If you provide a concrete class implementation of the repository than both methods must be implemented.

Comment: *unless the implementation is complete*: why would you add an incomplete implementation to the master/production/stable branch of your project in the first place? Just don't. Add it when it's ready, compete, and tested.

Comment: Because I said two methods but there are 10 of them and I can not implement all 10 and test them in one go. So was thinking of doing it in groups of 2-3 at a time.

Comment: But the complete methods in the Impl class, and leave the non-custom ones in the interface. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is when I implement i have to overwrite the methods without implementation. Now the functionality is breaking because of the incomplete implementation. So, I was thinking if I can force the use of interface till I complete all the methods that will not break the functionality and my code will work too.